# How to add full public directory to bundle all files in Webpack?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, webpack, mean-stack

i'm planning to use `webpack` instead of `gulp`. I'm using MEAN stack, I am using `AngularJs` for front end.

My `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './public/js/controllers.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    open: true,
    proxy: {
      '/': 'http://localhost:8080',
    },
  },
};
```

In this configuration i am bundling only `controller.js`, but i need to bundle whole folders which is inside in public directory, is it possible?

Comment: Have you referred to [this](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/)? You can enter an `array` of `strings` instead of a single `string`.

Comment: I dont understand, how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have two different `js` files(`controller1.js`, `controller2.js`) which you wish to include in `index.html`.

Your `webpack.config.js` will have `entry` as -

`entry : ['./public/js/controller1.js', './public/js/controller2.js']`

Both the controllers will be processed fine by `webpack`.

Comment: i have assets,js this two folders in my public, is it possile to bundle all?